# jasmine spyOn not reporting correctly for toHaveBeenCalled and toHaveBeenCalledWith

Tags: typescript, jasmine, spy

Code under test:

```
module lib {
    export class Topic {
        private _callbacks: JQueryCallback;
        public id: string;
        public publish: any;
        public subscribe: any;
        public unsubscribe: any;
        public test: any;

        constructor(id: string) {
            this.id = id;
            this._callbacks = jQuery.Callbacks();
            this.publish = this._callbacks.fire;
            this.subscribe = this._callbacks.add;
            this.unsubscribe = this._callbacks.remove;
        }
    }

    export class Bus {
        private static _topics: Object = {};

        static topic(id: string): Topic {
            var topic = id && this._topics[id];

            if (!topic) {
                topic = new Topic(id);
                if (id) {
                    this._topics[id] = topic;
                }
            }

            return topic;
        }
    }
}
```

Spec test objects:

```
module lib {
    class Person {
        private _dfd: JQueryDeferred<Topic>;
        private _topic: Topic;

        constructor(public firstName: string) {
            this._dfd = jQuery.Deferred();
            this._topic = Bus.topic("user:logon");
            this._dfd.done(this._topic.publish);
        }

        logon() {
            this._dfd.resolve(this);
        }
    }

    class ApiService {
        constructor() {
            Bus.topic("user:logon").subscribe(this.callLogonApi);
        }
        callLogonApi(person: Person) {
            console.log("Person.firstname: " + person.firstName);
        }
    }

    describe("Bus", () => {
        var person: Person;
        var apiService: ApiService;

        beforeEach(() => {
            person = new Person("Michael");
            apiService = new ApiService();
            spyOn(apiService, "callLogonApi");

                //or this fails as well
                //spyOn(apiService, "callLogonApi").and.callThrough();
            person.logon();
        });

        it("should create subscription and catch the published event", () => {
            expect(apiService.callLogonApi).toHaveBeenCalled();

                //this fails too 
            //expect(apiService.callLogonApi).toHaveBeenCalledWith(person);
        });
    });
}
```

The callLogonApi function is called and the console is written to as expected but the output is:

```
Expected spy callLogonApi to have been called.
Error: Expected spy callLogonApi to have been called.
```

*** This is now working with the constructor of ApiService changed to:

```
    constructor() {
        Bus.topic("user:logon").subscribe((data)=> { this.callLogonApi(data); });
    }
```

*** And the spyOn requires

```
        spyOn(apiService, "callLogonApi").and.callThrough();
```

Thanks to Ryan's great answer!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a smaller version of what's going on.

First, here's a simpler version of the `spyOn` method:

```
function spyOn(obj: any, methodName: string) {
    var prev = obj[methodName];
    obj[methodName] = function() {
        console.log(methodName + ' got called');
        prev();
    }
}
```

Now let's try this out with a simple class:

```
/** OK **/
class Thing1 {
    sayHello() {
        console.log('Hello, world');
    }
}

var x = new Thing1();
spyOn(x, 'sayHello');
x.sayHello(); // 'sayHello got called'
```

This works as expected. On to the deferred version, which is what your code is doing:

```
/** Not OK **/
class Thing2 {
    private helloMethod;

    constructor() {
        this.helloMethod = this.sayHello;
    }

    deferredHello() {
        window.setTimeout(this.helloMethod, 10);
    }

    sayHello() {
        console.log('Hello, world');
    }
}

var y = new Thing2();
spyOn(y, 'sayHello');
y.deferredHello(); // Why no spy?
```

Finally, the fixed version. I'll explain why it's fixed shortly:

```
/** OK now **/
class Thing3 {
    private helloMethod;

    constructor() {
        this.helloMethod = () => { this.sayHello(); }
    }

    deferredHello() {
        window.setTimeout(this.helloMethod, 10);
    }

    sayHello() {
        console.log('Hello, world');
    }   
}

var z = new Thing3();
spyOn(z, 'sayHello');
z.deferredHello(); // Spy works!
```

What's the deal?

Note that the `spyOn` function takes an object, wraps the method, and then sets a property *on the object itself* that replaces the spied function instance. This is very important because it changes where a property lookup of the method name will eventually happen.

In the normal case (`Thing1`), we overwrite a property (using `spyOn`) on `x` and then invoke that same method on `x`. Everything works because we're calling the exact same function that `spyOn` wrapped.

In the deferred case (`Thing2`), `y.sayHello` changes meaning throughout the code. When we first grab it in the constructor, we're getting the `sayHello` method *from the prototype* of the class. When we `spyOn` `y.sayHello`, the wrapped function is a new object, but the reference we got earlier in execution is still pointing to the implementation of `sayHello` in the prototype.

In the fixed case (`Thing3`), we use a function to more lazily get the value of `sayHello`, so when `z.sayHello` changes (because we spied it), the `deferredHello` invocation "sees" the new method object that's now on the instance object instead of the class prototype.

Comment: Ryan - What a great answer!! Thank you!